# Link a comment to a post revision

Tags: feature-request, comments, revisions-list

For example, in this answer:

[Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color/8318976#8318976)

If you read the comments, they are misleading. Everyone is saying the answer is wrong, while in fact, the errors in the answer were in its first few revisions.

My request is to mention next to a comment, during which revision the answer/question was when the comment was added, or at least just mention that the comment was added during an older revision without having to specify which one.

I've stumbled on quite a few answers on more than a few SE site (specially the older ones) where the comments where quite misleading due to them being added during an older revision.

Comment: This would be way too complicated and only few users will actually realize its meaning. If anything, maybe it's possible to ask for easier way to flag such comments e.g. add another review queue for comments.

Comment: There is of course the time of posting on the comment and the time of editing on the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If comment got outdated by answer's edit, flag it as obsolete. That's all.

Comments by their very nature are ephemeral. If something is supposed to stay, it should be an answer, or a part of one.

Comment: But sometimes those comments can be useful. I mean, knowing the wrong the stuff can be as important than knowing the right ones.

Comment: @Dan updated my answer.